# Can't get QT to work in Visual Studio 2019 and what is the best place to learn QT?

Tags: c++, qt

So I do know C++ fairly well, I have used it and C for the past year in college. I'm trying to make an application with a GUI that needs a simple input box and easily customizable windows. The main focus of the project however is a lot of backend processing, I just need a GUI for the user. Is there a place where I can just learn the quick basics of QT? Also for some reason I can't get QT to work on Visual Studio 2019.

I get this error:
[image: QT error 1]

When I go to input the version, it doesn't actually save when I click OK.

[image: qt version input]

[image: qt version error]

Comment: A mingw build of Qt will probably never work with Visual Studio.

Comment: You should have selected the VS version of Qt for VS....

Comment: one solution is  to use `Qt Creator` instead of visual studio

Answer (score 0):

In Manutention Tool you should download these Qt components marked as MSVC or UWP:

[image]

A MinGW build of Qt will probably work only with CLion and Qt Creator

And don't download the latest Qt, because VS doesn't work well with them.